# integration of a min function

Tags: statistics, integration

I cannot understand intermediate steps of a solution presented in an article. There is statistics involved, but I think my problem is with math.

Random variable $D$ (demand) is characterized by continuous cumulative distribution function $F(\xi)$ with probability density function  $f(\xi) = dF(\xi)$. Expected sales $S(Q)= E[\min\{D, Q\}]$. where $Q$ is supply.

[Please see the solution from the article](http://postimg.org/image/67833k5sl/) What are the intermediate transformations?

Thanks a lot.